# How can I add items to ChartSeries in my BarChartModel?

Tags: primefaces, charts

I'm using PrimeFaces, in order to build a BarChart. My goal is to compare some Testprojects to each other. Each Bar should be a Testproject from which you can read off the different Phases in which the project is situated.
My question is: I have a View where I can add new Testprojects. When I add one, there is a new Bar. But If I want to add another one, the old Bar is owerwritten. Of course It is, because of set... but I would like to do something like add(testprojectProducer.getTestproject().getName(), 1).
 The chart schould be able to remembe the old bar and add the new one. Is there a way or do I have to say goodby to primefaces and build my own chart?

Here is my code:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ChartView implements Serializable  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 9181815723688700642L;
private BarChartModel barModel;
@Inject 
private TestprojectProducer testprojectProducer;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createBarModel();
    new ArrayList<String>();  
}

private BarChartModel initBarModel() {

    BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel(); //Diagram
    ChartSeries cs= new ChartSeries();  // Balken
    cs.setLabel("Testprojekte");
    cs.set("Testprojekt 1",5);
    cs.set(testprojectProducer.getTestproject().getName(), 1);
    model.addSeries(cs);
    return model;
}   
    public void createBarModel() {

    barModel =initBarModel();
    barModel.setTitle("");
    barModel.setLegendPosition("");
    barModel.setSeriesColors("C80000");

    Axis xAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.X);
    xAxis.setLabel("Testprojekte");

    Axis yAxis = barModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setLabel("Phasen");
    yAxis.setMin(0);
    yAxis.setMax(7);

}

public BarChartModel getBarModel() {  

    return barModel;
}

public void setBarChartModel(BarChartModel barModel){
    this.barModel= barModel;
}


}
```

I hope there is a solution to my problem. Thank you!

Comment: _"Is there a way or do I have to say goodby to primefaces and build my own chart? "_ and then? Run into the same problem? If you overwrite the existing series it is ... well... overwritten... Why not 'add' a new Series to the existing model? Or if that is not the your problem, then please clarify...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. When you use 'HashMap', then It's not that hard:

```
   private BarChartModel initBarModel() {

    BarChartModel model = new BarChartModel(); 
    ChartSeries cc = new ChartSeries(); 
    cc.setLabel("Testprojekte");

    HashMap<Object, Number> groupData = new HashMap<Object, Number>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        groupData.put(testProjectListProducer.getList().get(i).getName(), 2);
    }
    cc.setData(groupData);
    model.addSeries(cc);

    return model;
}
```

Comment: So your question effectively was "How can I add items to a chartSeries" instead of "How can I add chartSeries". Please improve your title

Comment: Ok, I chanched the titel. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Now I look at your solution again, there is nothing in there to afterwards add additional nodes to the series, it is just initializing. Effectively there is nothing different than what is done in the [PrimeFaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/bar.xhtml)... And you did already add two nodes like this in your question, so I honestly fail to see the problem now and what this solves...